# Como enviar dados entre as Activitys sem abrir outra janela? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Boa tarde senhores, estou com um dúvida no meu código, eu preciso passar os dados de uma activity para outra porém quando eu coloco o valor ele abre a mesma tela duas vezes, ele está funcionando porém quando é colocado um valor no campo da activity ele abre outra tela porém com o valor informado, Poderiam me ajudar ? Segue abaixo meu código:

Activity que eu estou enviando :

```
public class NovaCor extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button botao1;
botao1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn1);

public void botao1(View v)
    {
        if (bool == false) {
            //String str1 = this.botao1.getBackground().toString();
            ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) this.botao1.getBackground();
            int colorInt = buttonColor.getColor();
            String colorHex = Integer.toHexString(colorInt);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), CriarCateg.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY", colorHex);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Activity que eu estou recebendo:

```
public class CriarCateg extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText descricao;
public EditText cor;
public Button altera;

 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        descricao = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.textViewDescrCateg);
        cor = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.txtviewcorcateg);
        altera = (Button) findViewById( R.id.alterarcor);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            String teste =  bundle.get("KEY").toString();
            this.cor.setText("#" + teste);
            altera.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+teste));



        }
    }
```

Comment: Quando clica no botão você só quer passar o bundle e não acessar a outra activity?

Comment: explique melhor o que você quer fazer, ficou meio confuso

Comment: Então, eu tenho uma tela e quando eu clico no botão "Criar Categoria" ele inicia uma nova activity com um novo layout, dentro do "Criar Categoria" tem outro botão chamado "Selecione a cor" que inicia outra activity com outro layout e com uma paleta de cores. Quando é selecionado uma cor ele abre novamente a activity do "Criar Categoria" com a cor selecionada, ou seja, ele mantém a activity "criar categoria" aberta duas vezes. O que eu queria é que ao invés dele abrir outra vez, ele preenchesse na que está aberta, porém meus testes não funcionaram.

Comment: resolveu com a minha resposta???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, na sua Activity CriarCateg, no botão que chama a Activity NovaCor, faça o seguinte:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), NovaCor.class);
            //inicia a activity desejada, enquanto está continua aberta esperando
            // um resultado
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Ainda dentro de CriarCateg, mas fora do onCreate, crie o método que receberá o resultado:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {

        String teste =  data.getStringExtra("KEY");
        this.cor.setText("#" + teste);
        altera.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+teste));
         }
    }
```

Já na Activity NovaCor no método de click do botão, deixe:

```
public void botao1(View v){
        if (bool == false) {
            ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) this.botao1.getBackground();
            int colorInt = buttonColor.getColor();
            String colorHex = Integer.toHexString(colorInt);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("KEY", colorHex);
            this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Você pode adicionar também caso o usuário aperte o botão voltar na Activity NovaCor.

Dentro da Activity Nova Cor, fora do onCreate, chame o método onBackPressed e deixe:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    finish();
}
```

E no método onActivityResult na Activity CriarCateg, após a condição if você pode colocar:

```
  else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nenhuma cor selecionada" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor marque-a como respondida e/ou como útil.